# Creating csv file using CsvHelper when number of headers are not fixed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, csvhelper

I have list of json objects. Each json object as has common properties and some properties unique to that json object. Like sample below

```
{"FirstName":"foo","LastName":"bar"}
{"FirstName":"jhon","LastName":"dow"}
{"FirstName":"james","LastName":"smith","Age":26}
{"LastName":"jones","Age":30, "Address":"1234 Test Drive"}
```

I want to create CSV report using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) where each property will be header. When property does not exists the value for that column should be empty

this my current implementation, which is ofcourse not considering extra properties

```
var records = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var jObj in result)
{
   var record = new ExpandoObject();
   foreach (var property in jObj)
   {
      record.TryAdd(property.Key, property.Value.ToString());
   }

   records.Add(record);
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}
```

So in above example the resulted csv should have 4 headers
`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Age` and `Address`

Note that the number of records could be in thousands

**Update 1**
below is my temporary solution until i find better way to do it without looping twice

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateCSVFromJObjects()
    {
        // arrange
        var list = new JObject[]
        {
            JObject.FromObject(new { FirstName = "foo",LastName = "bar" }),
            JObject.FromObject(new { FirstName = "john",LastName = "doe" }),
            JObject.FromObject(new { FirstName = "james",LastName = "smith", Age = 26 }),
            JObject.FromObject(new { LastName = "bar", Address = "123 Test Drive" })
        }.ToList();


        //act
        var headers = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var j in list)
        {
            foreach (var p in j)
            {
                if (!headers.Contains(p.Key))
                {
                    headers.Add(p.Key);
                }
            }
        }


        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\test.csv"))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(header);
                }
                await csv.NextRecordAsync();

                foreach (var jObj in list)
                {
                    foreach (var header in headers)
                    {
                        var token = jObj[header];
                        if (token != null)
                        {
                            csv.WriteField(token.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            csv.WriteField("");
                        }
                    }

                    await csv.NextRecordAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know all possible headers?

Comment: not known.. unless i loop though all JObjects first. That will cause looping twice

Comment: Can you deserialize the json to a type other then JObject? Writing a collection of objects works because the property names become headers.

Comment: The objects are not known. We have collection of json strings which i convert to JObjects. The number of properties in each JObject will not be more than 10 but number of JObjects could be in thousands

Comment: @LP13 Is the shown sample exactly how data will be provided?

Comment: the data shown is just a sample data. In production the property names would be different. The structure will be kind of similar. Also jobject will NOT have any deep hierarchy. Its only one level

Comment: @LP13 no what I meant was, are the objects going to be coming in an array/collection?  The shown JSON is just one object per line, which is not well formatted JSON so was wonder if that was the actual format of how the data would be read.

Comment: @Nkosi It will be a collection of Json string. I convert each string into JObject so eventually it will be collection of JObject

Answer (score 0):

If the result does not have to be streamed in real time with the processing, it may be more efficient to create and maintain the header-set and a header-list inside the same loop as the stream-write, skipping the header-write to the stream at first. Then you could build a new stream, write the header, then just Copy the original stream into it.

Whether you can use a memory stream for the intermediate write depends on your memory requirements.

Pseudo-code per request. This is really just a small rearrangement of your existing code. It requires less looping, but takes more memory or disk. The nature of the problem requires a trade off.

```
Stream intermediate_stream // memory or file
List headers // only add a set if List is a bottleneck (1000s of properties); list required to maintain ordering
foreach ( obj in list ) :
  foreach ( prop_name in obj.props )
    headers.add_if_unique(prop_name)
  foreach ( name in headers ) // to preserve ordering in output
   intermediate_stream.write(obj.prop_value(name))

Stream final_stream
final_stream.write(headers)
intermediate_stream.copy_to(final_stream)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example not sure I got it..paedo code will work